# Ipv4 mapped Ipv6 validation

Tags: php, ipv6

In the [rfc4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5)

said, that first 80 bits of this type of Ipv4 mapped Ipv6 address is 0.
How to check that with PHP?
I need more quick and safe way to do that instead of regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert the address from printable to binary form with `inet_pton`. That will give you a string where every charter corresponds to 8 bits of the address. Checking if the first 80 bits are zero is then as simple as checking the first 10 characters of the returned string:

```
$addr = '::10.1.2.3';
$bytes = inet_pton($addr);
if (substr($bytes, 0, 10) == "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00") {
  echo "Yes\n";
} else {
  echo "No\n";
}
```